# PyCharm type hint warning in `print()` function when passing in a file

Tags: python-3.x, types, pycharm

[image: Code screenshot]

The screenshot above is pretty self-explanatory. PyCharm throws a warning, but as far as I understand, the code above is a legitimate way of using the `print()` function, isn't it?

Comment: It's a known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16893